# Templated nested class not found C++

Tags: c++, windows, class, templates, nested

I am trying to write a portable Thread abstraction. Right now I have a code that compiles a dn works on Unix but doesn't compile on Windows (using VS2010).

```
class Thread
{
    public:
        Thread();
        ~Thread();
        template<typename Callable, typename Arg>
        void startThread(Callable c, Arg a);
        void killThread();

    private:

        template<typename Bind>
        struct nested
        {
            static DWORD WINAPI run(void *obj)
            {
                Bind * b = reinterpret_cast<Bind *>(obj);
                return (b->exec());
            }
        };

        template<typename Callable, typename Arg>
        class Binder
        {
            public:
                Binder(Callable c, Arg a): _call(c), _arg(a) {}
                ~Binder() {}
                DWORD operator()() {return (this->_call(this->_arg))}
                DWORD exec() {return (this->_call(this->_arg))}
            private:
                Callable _call;
                Arg      _arg;
        };
        HANDLE      _handle;
        DWORD       _id;
        bool        _isRunning;
        DWORD       _exitValue;
};

template<typename Callable, typename Arg>
void Thread::startThread(Callable c, Arg a)
{
    Thread::Binder<Callable, Arg> *b =
        new Thread::Binder<Callable, Arg>(c, a);
    CreateThread(0, 0,
            Thread::nested< Thread::Binder<Callable, Arg> >::run,
            b, 0, &this->_id);
}
```

When I try to compile, VS gives me an error C2039 :

`'nested<Thread::Binder<unsigned long (__cdecl*)(int *),int *> >' : is not a member of 'Thread'`

How come g++ can see it but not VS? Mostly I think it's because of the template specialization but how comes?

Comment: I don't see any specialization here.

Comment: This code would not compile using g++ 4.5.1 on Fedora 14. test.c:47:26: error: ‘class Thread’ has no member named ‘_id’

Comment: This code is the windows version so obviously, it won't compile on Fedora unless you change the DWORD to int.

Comment: Since I cannot edit your post please fix the syntax errors in `Binder::operator()` and `Binder::exec()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error indicates that VS 2010 cannot distinguish between a type and a class member in this situation. I don't know if this is a compiler bug or a bug in your code. You can resolve the issue by changing your code as follows:

```
    Thread::Binder<Callable, Arg> *b = new Thread::Binder<Callable, Arg>(c, a);
    typedef Thread::nested<Thread::Binder<Callable, Arg> > MyBinder;
    CreateThread(0, 0,
                 MyBinder::run,
                 b, 0, &this->_id);
```

On a related note, since you are using [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453.aspx) make sure you understand the implications of doing so as outlined in the Remarks section. If you plan to use the C run-time library (CRT) from your thread then don't use [CreateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682453.aspx).